# Form of affinely parametrized geodesic equation under an arbitrary coordinate transformation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, geometry, geodesics

This question is based off of Chapter 3 of Hobson M.P., G. P. Efstathiou, A. N. Lasenby General Relativity An Introduction for Physicists (2006).  The exact question is Q3.15.  Not for homework though, but studying for exams.

For an affinely parameterised geodesic $x^a(u)$ that is parameterised by an affine parameter u.

The geodesic satisfies:

$$ \frac{d^2x^a}{du^2 }=\Gamma^{a}_{bc}\frac{d^2x^b}{du^2}\frac{d^2x^c}{du^2}$$

Under an arbitrary coordinate transformation $x^a \rightarrow x'^a$, the form of the equation should be unchanged.  How do I show this?  I am a little mixed up, does an arbitrary coordinate transformation just entail a change of parameter, e.g. $u \rightarrow u' $ or is the parameter changed to the new coordinate e.g. $x^a(u) \rightarrow x'^a(x^a) $ ?  How do the coordinate vectors (e.g. $e^a $)change under a transformation?

Some thoughts I had on this:

- If a coordinate transformation is just a parameter change, could I
  just represent the derivatives as:
  $$ \frac{d^2x^a}{du^2 } \rightarrow \frac{d^2x^a}{du^2
     }\frac{d^2u}{du'^2 }$$

  And the connection changes to: $$\Gamma^{a}_{bc} \rightarrow
     \Gamma'^{a}_{bc}=\frac{\partial x'^a }{\partial x^d }\frac{\partial
     x^f }{\partial x'^b }\frac{\partial x^g }{\partial x'^c }
     \Gamma'^{d}_{fg}+\frac{\partial x'^a }{\partial x^d }\frac{\partial^2
     x'^a }{\partial x'^c \partial x'^b  }$$ and then insert into the differential geodesic equation and evaluate?
- Or do I need to specify a general coordinate transformation equation? e.g. a linear
  transformation $x'^1= \alpha x^1 + \beta $ and then insert this into the original geodesic differential equation?

A quick explanation of the form of a geodesic $x^a(u)$ (i.e. is this similar to an equation of a line like $y=mx+c$) and what happens under arbitrary coordinate transformations in general, would be very useful in understanding this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The geodesic equation is
$$
\frac{ d^2 x^\lambda }{ d\tau^2} + \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}(x) \frac{ d x^\mu }{ d \tau} \frac{ d x^\nu }{ d \tau}   = 0 ~. 
$$
Under $x^\mu \to x'^\mu(x)$, we note that the Christoffel symbol does not transform like a tensor. Rather,
$$
\Gamma'^\lambda_{\mu\nu}(x') =\frac{ \partial x^\alpha}{ \partial x'^\mu} \frac{ \partial x^\beta}{ \partial x'^\nu} \left[  \frac{\partial x'^\lambda}{\partial  x^\rho}  \Gamma^\rho_{\alpha\beta}(x) -  \frac{ \partial^2 x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\alpha \partial x^\beta }  \right]
$$
We also have
\begin{align}
\frac{d x'^\lambda }{ d\tau} &= \frac{ \partial x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\rho } \frac{ d x^\rho }{ d\tau}~, \\
\qquad \frac{d^2 x'^\lambda }{ d\tau^2} &= \frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \frac{ \partial x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\rho } \frac{ d x^\rho }{ d\tau} \right) = \frac{ \partial x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\rho } \frac{ d^2x^\rho }{ d\tau^2} + \frac{ \partial^2 x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\alpha \partial x^\beta }  \frac{ d x^\alpha }{ d\tau} \frac{ d x^\beta }{ d\tau} ~. 
\end{align}
Thus,
$$
\Gamma'^\lambda_{\mu\nu}(x') \frac{ d x'^\mu }{ d \tau} \frac{ d x'^\nu }{ d \tau}  =  \left[  \frac{\partial x'^\lambda}{\partial  x^\rho}  \Gamma^\rho_{\alpha\beta}(x) -  \frac{ \partial^2 x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\alpha \partial x^\beta } \right]   \frac{ d x^\alpha }{ d \tau} \frac{ d x^\beta }{ d \tau}
$$
Putting this altogether, we find
\begin{align}
&\frac{ d^2 x'^\lambda }{ d\tau^2} + \Gamma'^\lambda_{\mu\nu}(x') \frac{ d x'^\mu }{ d \tau} \frac{ d x'^\nu }{ d \tau}   \\
&\qquad= \frac{ \partial x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\rho } \frac{ d^2x^\rho }{ d\tau^2} + \frac{ \partial^2 x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\alpha \partial x^\beta }  \frac{ d x^\alpha }{ d\tau} \frac{ d x^\beta }{ d\tau} + \left[  \frac{\partial x'^\lambda}{\partial  x^\rho}  \Gamma^\rho_{\alpha\beta}(x) -  \frac{ \partial^2 x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\alpha \partial x^\beta } \right]   \frac{ d x^\alpha }{ d \tau} \frac{ d x^\beta }{ d \tau} \\
&\qquad= \frac{ \partial x'^\lambda }{ \partial x^\rho } \left[  \frac{ d^2x^\rho }{ d\tau^2}  +   \Gamma^\rho_{\alpha\beta}(x)  \frac{ d x^\alpha }{ d \tau} \frac{ d x^\beta }{ d \tau}  \right] \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that cleared up the confusion I was having.

Comment: Your equation that describes the transformation property of the Christoffel symbol seems to differ from the one that I know [(see this MathSE post)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248267/christoffel-symbol-transformation-law). Cloud you maybe explain shorty where the change in sign comes from?

Comment: @Sito you can work out what the sign should be using the definition.

Comment: [This](https://www.general-relativity.net/2019/03/transformation-of-christoffel-symbol.html) is how I would derive it. The expression at the end (eq. 16) is obviously different to the one that you stated. Is there a way to show that they are equivalent?

Comment: @Sito - The first line (and therefore all subsequent lines) of the equation under equation (3) in your link is wrong. You do not have the current transformation law for the metric. On the LHS, your primed indices are lowered whereas on the RHS they are raised. There might be other mistakes but I haven't looked at your derivation beyond this point. A quick glance tells me that you have similar index problems all over the place (for example - your equation (17) is MOST definitely wrong -- the indices just don't match up on both sides).

Comment: You're right, the first eq. under (3) is wrong, but the second eq. under (3) is correct again (and as far as I can see, the rest is too). Eq. (17) is wrong, yes, but that's actually the whole point of the post... But my confusion was cleared, [this post](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/christoffel-symbols-transformation-law.877865/post-5513984) shows how its possible to have a different sign (with different indices, admittedly).